# Loop through a pivot table and save each field's details in a separate workbook with the field's name

Tags: excel, vba, split, pivot-table

I'm working on a project in Excel where I have a pivot table with people's name and their associated claims. I need to double click on each name in the table and when the details (claims details) show up in a separate sheet save the sheet as a separate workbook with that person's name in a folder. Is there any way to automate this process in VBA?

I have the code below which works for the first item but it has a few problems:

-The name of the sheet and the workbook are hard coded and therefore only work for the first item. Is there anyway to just select the new sheet instead of selecting it by name? And is there a way to use the item's name instead of Book3.xlsx?

Here is my code:

```
Sub IndividualReports()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Table").Select

  With Application.ActiveSheet
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

For i = 8 To LastRow
  Range("C" & i).Select
  Selection.ShowDetail = True
  Sheets("Sheet2").Select
  Sheets("Sheet2").Move
  Sheets("Sheet2").Select
  ChDir "C:\Users\haghigy\Desktop\New3"
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\haghigy\Desktop\New3\Book3.xlsx", _
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

*Edit: Here is my code after the solution.

```
Sub IndividualReports()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Name As String
Dim Path As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    Path = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = Path
    Set fldr = Nothing

Sheets("Table").Select
    With Application.ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

For i = 6 To LastRow - 1

Name = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Table").Rang("A6:A200"), i - 5)
Range("C" & i).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
ActiveSheet.Move
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Name, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please show us what you have tried yourself?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51972957/edit) you question to add more info.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm new to VBA so I wasn't sure if it's better to post what I have or just start from scratch. I updated my question with the code I have right now

Comment: I think it's always best to start with what you have so far. I would, as a best practice, recommend against having On Error Resume Next and turning off screen updating while debugging at least. The errors can give you a clue where you're going wrong, and it's helpful to see what you are doing while stepping through the code (F8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great start! A couple things I noticed. First and foremost, when you move the detail sheet to a new workbook and save as, your workbook with the Pivot table is no longer the active workbook. So selecting the range on the new workbook won't work. You could add

```
Workbooks("[WorkbookName].xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Table").Activate
```

to the top of your loop. Further,

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Move
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
```

The two Select methods aren't needed, and the Sheet numbers will increment, so it won't always be Sheet2. You could replace the block above with:

```
ActiveSheet.Move
```

Finally you would have to change the name of the workbook you are saving so it doesn't just overwrite each time. Maybe like:

```
filename:="C:\Users\haghigy\Desktop\New3\Book" & i & ".xlsx"
```

Then it should work.

*edit: also don't really need the ChDir

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I changed my code and it works perfectly.